# Can’t Determine charger is compatible?

Tags: asus-laptop, charger, voltage

The original charger that came with my laptop:
**input: 100-240v ~ 1.2A 50-60Hz

output: 19v 2.37A**

The new charger that I got:
**input: 100-240v ~ 2.5A 50-60Hz

output: 19.5v 4.62A**

Will this charger be compatible with my laptop? (Laptop Model# S510UA-DB71)

Comment: Do both have the same connector type, size & polarity?

Answer (score 0):

The new charger provides more power (about 2 times the power of the original) than needed. That shouldn't be a problem. And the 0.5V difference in output should also be in the tolerance range.

*Disclaimer:*
Generally, many things could go wrong, so do this at your own risk.